# Reverse column contents to utilize index?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Based on the query I'm running now I assume this is a pipe dream:

I have an index on a column that contains a string id. Those IDs have an identifier on the end, so to capture the data I need I need to pattern match like so:

```
key LIKE '%racecar'
```

Since you can't take advantage of an index with the wildcard starting the string, I was hoping I could do this:

```
reverse(key) LIKE 'racecar%'
```

But, this would mean MySQL has to look at, and perform a function on, every single row anyway, is that correct? Any other ways to get around this issue short of changing the naming conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like bad DB design. Split the string and the id into two separate columns and the problem(and many other problems) will be automatically solved.

I also doubt the order of the string and the id will make difference to MYSQL with respect to performance.

Also keep in mind you have an index over key, but this does not mean you have an index over the reverse of `key` which is the reason you get no speedup at all. I believe that given the situation the performance is beyond salvation.

Comment: I hear that, but the DB contents itself is far outside of my control.

Comment: @Chords I have added some more text that I hope will make my point clearer.